# How to refresh parent fancybox when child fancybox closes?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Here's my parent fancybox:

```
$("a.fb").fancybox({
'autoScale': true,
'opacity': false,
'overlayShow': false,
'width': '90%',
'height': '90%',
'type': 'iframe',
'scrolling': 'yes',
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic',
'titlePosition': 'outside',
'overlayColor': '#000',
'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
'titleFormat': function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {return '<span 
id="fancybox-title-over">' + title + '</span>';}
});
```

The child fancybox it calls is via this element:

```
<a class="fbchild" href="AddCode.aspx?Type=<%: System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(Session["CodeTypeID"].ToString()) %>" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: small; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000" title="Add New Code">Add New <%: System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(Session["CodeType"].ToString()) %></a>
```

and finally, the fbchild class is defined as:

```
$("a.fbchild").fancybox({
'autoScale': true,
'opacity': false,
onClosed: function () {parent.location.reload(true);},
'overlayShow': false,
'width': '90%',
'height': '90%',
'type': 'iframe',
'scrolling': 'yes',
'transitionIn': 'elastic',
'transitionOut': 'elastic',
'titlePosition': 'outside',
'overlayColor': '#000',
'overlayOpacity': 0.9,
'titleFormat': function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {return '<span 
id="fancybox-title-over">' + title + '</span>';}
});
```

The problem is, when I close the child, the parent closes as well, and the aspx page where the parent came from gets refreshed.  How do I refresh the parent fancybox?

Comment: what version of fancybox? are you opening a fancybox inside another fancybox?

Comment: Yes, I am opening one inside another.  The version is 1.3

Comment: `afterClose` is not a valid API option for fancyBox v1.3.x, how come is working? are you sure about your fancyBox version? can you share a link to your working page?

Comment: I know afterClose works with version 2.0.  I mistakenly put it in just to make sure I was running the right version.  I have replaced it with  'onClosed': function() {
     parent.location.reload(true); 
    ;}

Comment: Tried this as well, but both parent and child close, and I am back to my non-fancybox page.

   protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
   {
     close();
   }
   
   void close()
   {
     string script = "parent.$.fancybox.close();";
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "close", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script>", script));
   }

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I solved this :)

```
    protected void FormView1_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
    close();
    }
    void close()
    {
    string script = "parent.location.reload(true);parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "close", string.Format(<script type='text/javascript'>{0}</script>", script));
    }
```

The parent.location.reload(true); refreshes the parent, and the close() closes the child.  Sweet!!